# Find how many n-digit positive integers using the digits 1, 2, and 3, such that no two 1's are next to each other.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

I found this problem in section $5$ of "A path to combinatorics for undergraduates" from Titu Andreescu, but I don't know what's wrong with my solution.

First I defined $A_n$ to be the set of "good numbers" and $a_n = |A_n|$ (those that satisfy the problem statement). Now we let $B_n \subseteq A_n$ such that $B_n$ consists of the good numbers whose last digit is $1$ and $b_n = |B_n|$.

Now given a $n+1$-digit good number, the first $n$ digits must be a good number; so by taking an $n$-digit good number, if this number is in $B_n$ then we can construct only $2$ good numbers because we cannot add a $1$ to the end. On the other hand if the number isn't in $B_n$ we can add any of the three digits to the end to obtain a $n+1$-digit. So based on this my thought was that we can write the recursion:

$a_n = 2b_n + 3(a_n-b_n) = 3a_n - b_n$

Where $a_1 = 3$ and $a_2 = 8$ (when $n = 2$ the only bad number is $11$). However for the case where $n = 3$ we get $a_n = 3(8)-3 = 21$ but in reality only $111,112,211,113,311$ so the ammount of good numbers is $22$. Can anyone explain to me why my solution is wrong? And how to actually solve the problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. In this way you don't seem include numbers like  111 as you don' t want to obtain end with 1 from B-type number.           2. You can get good number from bad one by adding 1 to the end if it ends with one.

Comment: You're saying that bad numbers are those with exactly two consecutive ones and if there's more than two consecutive two's then the number is good?
Because I'm saying that 111 is a bad number

Comment: $B_{2}=\{21, 31\}$ right? so $b_{2}=2$. Then your formula should be $a_{3}=3(8)-2=22$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recursive Relation**

There is a mistake in your recursive relation. The correct relation should be:

$$
a_{n+1}=3a_{n}-b_{n}
$$

This is only one half of the relation. You also need a formula to get $b_{n+1}$. Each number in $B_{n+1}$ is a good number with $n$ digits that does not end with $1$, followed by an extra $1$ at the end. Therefore, we have

$$
b_{n+1}=a_{n}-b_{n}
$$

**Matrix Form**

Common way to solve the problem is using the matrix form:

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\ 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Equivalently,

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1 \\ 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{1} \\ b_{1}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

**Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors**

The eigenvalue - eigenvector pairs of the square matrix are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_{1}=1+\sqrt{3},&\phantom{x}\mathbf{v}_{1}=\begin{Bmatrix}1 & 2-\sqrt{3}\end{Bmatrix}^{\top}
\\
\lambda_{2}=1-\sqrt{3},&\phantom{x}\mathbf{v}_{2}=\begin{Bmatrix}1 & 2+\sqrt{3}\end{Bmatrix}^{\top}
\end{aligned}
$$

Using these results, we have

$$
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{Bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2-\sqrt{3} & 2+\sqrt{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^{n-1} & 0 \\
0 & \left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2-\sqrt{3} & 2+\sqrt{3}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{Bmatrix}
a_{1} \\ b_{1}
\end{Bmatrix}
$$

Substituting $a_{1}=3$ and $b_{1}=1$, we have:

$$
a_{n}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^{n}+
\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{3}\right)\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)^{n}
$$